# Magento 2: redirect to home

Tags: magento2, redirect, home-page, view

I want to redirect my view to the homepage after data submitted in a custom form

> $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');

This code leads to redirection, for now, please help

Also is it possible to get a delay of 5-10 sec in  redirection

Comment: Why you need delay?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('cms/index/index');
```

if you need to delay, use function sleep() of php

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use below code in Action controller

```
$this->_redirect('cms/index/index');
```

For delay in redirect, you can use **sleep(5);**

Please let me know if you find any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

There is a best example for redirect page after some time is customer logout.

You can use below code to redirect specific page.

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('Your redirect path');
```

For delay logic, you have to use the below script.

```
<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/mage"
], function($){

    $($.mage.redirect("<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl())) ?>", "assign", 5000));

});
</script>
```

**Note:** Above code is not tested i have just share logic. you have to change or apply logic as per your requirement.

I hope it helps!